# What is wrong with my gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

What is wrong with my `.gitignore` file?

```
build/
/build
/*/build/
/*/*/build/
build/
```

This is the structure of my directory:

```
myroot
    FacebookSDK
       +--src
       +--build
           +--foo
           +-- bar  
    app
       +--scr
       +--build         
    build
        +--other stuff...
        +--other stuff..
    .gitignore
    other stuff...
```

The problem is that **foo** and **bar** are not ignored!

What could be going wrong?

```
xxxxs-my:xxxx xxx$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.iml
modified:   FacebookSDK/build.gradle
modified:   FacebookSDK/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/classes.jar
modified:       FacebookSDK/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/res/drawable/com_facebook_button_blue.xml
```

Comment: Have you already committed those directory ? if you did that, you must to delete "build" repertory of your GIT and after "build" and other subfolders will be correctly ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only need this rule, [per the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

```
**/build
```

This will exclude `build` folders globally.

If any of those folders had been added prior, you'd have to remove it from Git via `git rm`.

What's actually *wrong* with your `.gitignore`:

- `/build` and `build/` are equivalent; they will match a top-level `build/` folder.
- `/*/build` and `/*/*/build` wouldn't match anything.

Comment: I don't know, same result :-((((

Comment: Are you sure that those files weren't previously added to Git before?  If you do a `git status && git add .`, does it still pick them up?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because three of your ignore lines are from the root directory:

```
/build
/*/build/
/*/*/build/
```

when they should be from the current directory:

```
./build
./*/build/
./*/*/build/
```

Comment: It's from the context of the Git folder.  Remember:  Git doesn't care about anything not in its tracker.

Comment: Ah, I see. Would it not work if she just had `*/build/` then rather than any forward slashes tacked onto the front to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
build/
**/build/
```

in the .gitignore

If the files are already tracked use `git rm --cached myfile` to remove them from version control but keep them in local repo. Once removed from version control they should not get detected on change.